# React-native-video not working for android

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I'm trying to play videos on my react-native project for android.

**Installed**

> react-native-video && react-native link

I can't play `local storage` and `online videos`.

**problem**

- Sometimes audio only coming with the white screen.
- sometimes video is flickering.

**package,json**

```
{
  "name": "viapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-video": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "23.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'viapp'
include ':react-native-video'
project(':react-native-video').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android')
include ':app'
```

**Build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
package com.viapp;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.brentvatne.react.ReactVideoPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new ReactVideoPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import Video from 'react-native-video';
import Dog from './dog.mp4';
import LightVideo from "./lights.mp4";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Video
          source={LightVideo}
          resizeMode="cover"
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}



// Later on in your styles..


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

I don't know where i made mistake.I tried `uri` it also not working.the version is doubtfull for me.

**Any help would be really appreciated**

Comment: Could you find any solution? I can't show on Android as well